# Retrieving positions of 1's in a tensor or splitting the tensor at 1's

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am looking to do positional encodings based on word lengths.
After some "pre-processing" of the word boundaries (they are also used in other parts of the network) I am looking at a tensor with `0's` and `1's` where 1 is the beginning of a word and 0 some part in the word. An example would be `[1,0,0,1,0,0] or [1,0,1,1]`. The desired output is to be either the positions of the `1's` (from which is can then calculate the word legnths) or directly split into a list of tensors which each seperatly is as long as the word (pretty much split at every `1` so splitting `[1,0,1,1]` into `[[1,0],[1],[1]]`. 
Since pretty much only the length is important the exact output is not set in stone, as long as it is possible to retrieve the different word lenghts (in correct order) for word positional encodings. The values in search are `3,3` for the first example and `2,1,1` for the second.
I was thinking about `tf.argmax` but it does only give the position of one maximum, not of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to finde the indices of the 1's: 
Let `max = [1,0,1,1]` then `tf.boolean_mask(tf.range(max.shape[0]),max)` returns a tensor that has the inidices of all 1's in it.